# Given a debian source package - How do I install the build-deps?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, package-management, apt, dpkg

I have a debian (well technically ubuntu) source package, i.e. the .dsc, the .tar.gz, etc., I want to build this. The `dpkg-buildpackage` fails, since I don't have all the build dependencies.

Normally I'd use `apt-get build-dep`, but this package isn't in apt.

Is there a 'clean', 'proper' way to install all the build dependencies, given a source package. I know I could just open the debian/control file,  but I'm curious if there's a 'proper' way.

I have installed `build-essential`, and have all the normal compilers etc., this package requires extra software.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually I can use `dpkg-checkbuilddeps` which shows the build dependencies. That gets me 99% of what I need

Comment: oddly enough, the *packagename-version.dsc* file contains the build dependencies in the line that begins with the string **Build-Depends**

Answer (score 47):

Use `mk-build-deps` which is part of `devscripts`.

Comment: For those looking to create a source package for normal depends, use `equivs-build`. This would be the "other half" of `mk-build-deps`.

Answer (score 24):

Here is an example workflow using ptman's suggestion.

Assuming you have downloaded the `.dsc` file, the `.orig.*z` file, and maybe also a `.debian.*z` file, then unpack the source package with:

```
dpkg-source -x [package_name]_[package_version].dsc
```

Move into the extracted source folder and run:

```
sudo mk-build-deps -i
```

This will create the file `[package_name]-build-deps_[version].deb` and install it, and also install all the dependencies it suggests.

Now you should be able to build your package from source:

```
debuild
```

When you are finished, you can easily remove the dependencies that were pulled in, by removing the `build-deps` package which you generated:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove [package_name]-build-deps
```

Comment: You can also pass `-r` to `sudo mk-build-deps -i` to remove the package after installing it. Also, instead of building as root, you can install as root using `--root-cmd sudo`. In the end, use `mk-build-deps --install --root-cmd sudo --remove`

Comment: Also, you may need to `sudo apt install devscripts equivs` first.

Answer (score 6):

I usually use `debuild` from `devscripts` to build packages, and if relevent it prints a line of the missing build-deps.

The "proper" way is to use `pbuilder` or similar which will build the package in a minimal `chroot`, and just install any additional build-deps as specified by the package, this also removes a bunch of other potential issues (local installations of non-packaged libraries for example).

Answer (score 1):

The annoying bit about dpkg-checkbuilddeps is that it also prints the version constraints and alternatives for the installation, such that its output cannot be directly forwarded to apt-get/apt/debfoster/.. .

I would like to point to "apt-get build-dep" again, but suggest to add the current directory, i.e. root of the source package that features the debian subdirectory, as a package "name", so the invocation is:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep .
```

Answer (score 0):

The file debian/control lists all the packages that should be installed as build-dependencies. If (for whatever reason) you have installed some of the required software without the apt system, then just remove respective lines from the debian/control file, so dpkg-buildpackage will not know about these packages and not check on them.

Another trick is to execute the build instructions directly, which also circumvents any extra checks by dpkg-buildpackage and that also does not perform the cleaning of the build files (helps with incremental local fixes) by executing `fakeroot ./debian/rules binary` instead of dpkg-buildpackage.

Answer (score -7):

Try:

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: I have install build-essential. This package requires extra software.

Comment: And it doesn't explain what requires?
maybe libncurses-dev also.

Comment: That's not the point; of course it does. The point is to have a command that actually installs the dependencies, not one that just displays them.