# dpkg-checkbuilddeps?

Tags: debian, dependencies, dpkg

I'm trying to build an application from source on a Debian machine; the source code includes a '`debian`' directory with all the files required to build the package (control/rules etc.).

When I run `dpkg-buildpackage`, it fails because I don't have the required dependencies.  OK.

So, I run `dpkg-checkbuilddeps`, which gives me a very clear list of what the package dependencies are.

Am I now expected to verify the (parse-unfriendly) output of that tool manually?  And then install each package myself?  It seems insane to me to have such high quality tools that only get you 90% to your goal, so **I** must be doing something wrong.

How might I get from `dpkg-checkbuilddeps` to '*done*'?

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate I see: http://serverfault.com/questions/127625/given-a-debian-source-package-how-do-i-install-the-build-deps/127679#127679

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the package source folder,

```
sudo mk-build-deps -i -t aptitude
```

will build, and install with aptitude, a package that pulls the build dependencies you need. `mk-build-deps` is part of the [`devscripts`](http://packages.debian.org/sid/devscripts) package.

Answer (score 1):

Is this package a debian source package obtained via `apt-get source`?  If so, you can just `apt-get build-dep <packagename>`.

You may be using this already - but this is one of my [debian bible pages](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=228570) - building packages.